Erro: "No overload matches this call"
Fala Dev's,  boa noite!
Estou desenvolvendo uma API usando TypeScript e estou enfrentando um erro de sobrecarga, tentei encontrar uma solução mas não consegui. Esse erro aparece no código dos EndPoints, vou deixar um print e o código desse erro.
Desde já, agradeço pela atenção. ✌
Código do Erro:
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(req: Request, res: Response) => express.Response<any, Record<string, any>> | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Application<Record<string, any>>'.
      Type '(req: Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>, res: Response<any, Record<string, any>>) => Response<...> | undefined' is missing the following properties from type 'Application<Record<string, any>>': init, defaultConfiguration, engine, set, and 63 more.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(164, 5): The last overload is declared here.
(alias) interface Response<ResBody = any, Locals extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>>
import Response

Código completo(TypeScript):
import express, { Application, Request, Response } from 'express';
    
const app: Application = express();  // Tipagem explícita para Express
    
app.use(express.json());
    
// Definição de tipos para os builds
interface Build {
   id: number;
   nome: string;
   equipamentos: string[];
   armas: string[];
   modificacoes: string[];
}
    
app.use(express.json());
    
let builds: Build[] = [
      { id: 1, nome: 'Build Sniper', equipamentos: ['Colete balístico', 'Luvas reforçadas'], armas: ['Rifle de precisão', 'Pistola'], modificacoes: ['Mira telescópica', 'Estabilizador de recuo'] },
      { id: 2, nome: 'Build Assalto', equipamentos: ['Colete tático', 'Capacete reforçado'], armas: ['Fuzil de assalto', 'Escopeta'], modificacoes: ['Mira holográfica', 'Carregador estendido'] },
      { id: 3, nome: 'Build Tank', equipamentos: ['Escudo balístico', 'Colete à prova de balas'], armas: ['Escopeta', 'SMG'], modificacoes: ['Blindagem reforçada', 'Redução de recuo'] }
    ];
    
    app.get('/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
        res.send('API rodando!');
    });
    
    // GET todos os builds
    app.get('/builds', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
      res.json(builds);
    });
    
    // GET build por ID
    app.get('/builds/:id', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
      const id = parseInt(req.params.id);
      const build = builds.find(b => b.id === id);
      
      if (!build) {
        return res.status(404).send('Build não encontrado');
      }
    
      res.json(build);
    });
    
    // GET builds por nome (busca com query params)
    app.get('/builds/search', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
      const nome = req.query.nome as string;  // Garantir que nome seja tratado como string
      
      if (!nome) {
        return res.status(400).send('É necessário fornecer um nome para a busca.');
      }
    
      const resultados = builds.filter(build =>
        build.nome.toLowerCase().includes(nome.toLowerCase())
      );
    
      if (resultados.length === 0) {
        return res.status(404).send('Nenhum build encontrado com o nome fornecido.');
      }
    
      res.json(resultados);
    });
    
    // POST criar um novo build
    app.post('/builds', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
      const novoBuild: Build = {
        id: builds.length + 1,
        nome: req.body.nome,
        equipamentos: req.body.equipamentos,
        armas: req.body.armas,
        modificacoes: req.body.modificacoes
      };
    
      builds.push(novoBuild);
      res.status(201).json(novoBuild);
    });
    
    // PUT atualizar um build existente por ID
    app.put('/builds/:id', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
      const id = parseInt(req.params.id);
      const build = builds.find(b => b.id === id);
      
      if (!build) {
        return res.status(404).send('Build não encontrado');
      }
    
      build.nome = req.body.nome;
      build.equipamentos = req.body.equipamentos;
      build.armas = req.body.armas;
      build.modificacoes = req.body.modificacoes;
    
      res.json(build);
    });
    
    // DELETE deletar um build por ID
    app.delete('/builds/:id', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
      const id = parseInt(req.params.id);
      const index = builds.findIndex(b => b.id === id);
      
      if (index === -1) {
        return res.status(404).send('Build não encontrado');
      }
    
      builds.splice(index, 1);
      res.status(204).send();
    });
    
    // Porta do servidor
    const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`Servidor rodando na porta ${port}`);
    });


olá João, não adicione prints/imagens de código, adicione o código diretamente na pergunta, a visualização é muito melhor. Pode clicar em Editar para alterar a sua pergunta

Aparentemente é o Typescript ficando mais "chatinho", mas imagino que tenham base sólida para fazer essa mudança.
Eu estava exatamente com o mesmo problema agora e basicamente substitui como o abaixo:
app.get('/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.send('API rodando!');
});

Para
app.get('/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.send('API rodando!');
    return
});

Encontrei a resposta nesse comentário no GitHub.

Fiz a alteração que você indicou, mas ainda sim continuou com o erro. Vou continuar tentando, qualquer coisa eu comento aqui. Mas, agradeço pela dica. ✌

Você alterou todos os returns ou só o que eu indiquei? Precisa alterar todos para o typescript parar de reclamar
